# Transposing Black to White in TIF & JPG Images

Tags: windows, gimp

I have a large number of tif and jpg images with coloured lines (scope traces if it matters) on a black background. Only the background is black. I want a quick simple way to change the black pixels to white, maybe a little excutable run off a Win command line. Alternatively maybe Gimp or Photopad, both of which I have? Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)?

An example of the command would be:

```
convert SOURCE.jpg -fuzz 10% -fill white +opaque black -fill white -opaque black DESTINATION.jpg
```

Source: http://www.laurii.info/2011/07/replace-colour-image-imagemagick-batchable/